# Google sheets: image disappears after assignScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I added an image to a cell successfully, but if I assigned a function programmatically it doesn't appear anymore.

```
const data = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode("<my base64 string>", "image/png", "run")
const image = sheet.insertImage(data, 1, 4)
```

This will correctly show the image in that cell. When I add:

```
image.assignScript("show")
```

the image doesn't appear anymore.
`show` is an existing function. If I assign that script manually to the image it works correctly.

Edit: the same is happening if I use `setWidth` or `setHeight` in place of `assignScript`

Edit(2): I've just found that it's disappearing only on the first execution. If I refresh the page then it works correctly but it always needs the refresh to work properly.

Some more code details:
From menu I call a function which in the end calls the addButton function:

```
function onOpen(){
  const UI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui.createMenu('My menu')
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Templates')
    .addItem('Item 1', 'myFunctionForItem1')
    ...
  ).addToUi()
}

function myFunctionForItem1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("title",0)
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  //insert some templates (arrays of strings)
  sheet.getRange(1,1,template.length,template[0].length).setValues(template)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  addRunButton(2, 1, 'show')
}

function addRunButton(row, column, fun) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const data = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode("<my base64 string>", "image/png", "run")
  const image = sheet.insertImage(data, column, row)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  image.assignScript(fun)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
}
```

Comment: I tried this with the minimal amount of code to be like your sample and the image didn't disappear. Can you share the rest of your relevant code?

Comment: Hey @Daniel, I shared some more code, and maybe another important detail (look at Edit(2))

Comment: I thought that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57248310 How about this?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, yes thanks, that's exactly the same problem. I got inspiration from your answer and slightly improved it. Although I'm not so happy of final result, it's still the best workaround I found

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply of `that's exactly the same problem.`, I flagged it as a duplicate question.

Comment: Ok, I'll post my solution on that question

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the same issue mentioned by @Tanaike. His answer inspired me to find a workaround, but this is clearly a bug in Google Apps Scripts, and couldn't completely fix it.

As Tanaike said, the button appears after a refresh or after a tab switch. I slightly improved his solution:
basically, I create a new sheet and hide it immediately, then fill it (with also image) and finally show it to the user.
This is a small improvement that allows for reducing the flickering between tabs.

```
const sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(title, 0).hideSheet()
// fill sheet
sheet.showSheet()
Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet)
```

Comment: If you added a answer there, you may delete this one. As to downvotes, I can only speculate that it's due to a lack of research/[mcve] in the first version of your question. People probably wasted time trying to reproduce the issue: In the future, always add the complete code(not just snippets) and make sure it's reproducible in a new sheet and script, i.e., all the edits to the question should've been in the initial version of your question.